# How to open a trade on the following trading day in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create a simple long only trading strategy on the daily timeframe that opens a position on a specific day of the year and closes the position on another specific day of the year. This repeats every year. The problem is that if the day set is X and the following day X+1 is not a business day (weekend/public holiday), the position won't be opened. How can I edit the code so that in that case the trade opens on the following business day?

For example in OANDA:XAGUSD, the strategy does not make any trade in 2018 and 2019 for mentioned reason.

```
//@version=5
strategy('Seasonal Trading Strategy', overlay=true, initial_capital = 10000, pyramiding = 0, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100)

// Input to enable or disable Rule 1
enableRule1 = input(true, 'Rule 1')

// Input for long position opening date - Rule 1
longEntryMonth1 = input.int(6, 'Entry Month (1-12)', minval = 1, maxval = 12)
longEntryDay1 = input.int(29, 'Entry Day (1-31)', minval = 1, maxval = 31)

// Input for long position closing date - Rule 1
longExitMonth1 = input.int(8, 'Exit Month (1-12)', minval = 1, maxval = 12)
longExitDay1 = input.int(30, 'Exit Day (1-31)', minval = 1, maxval = 31)

// Check current date
currentMonth = month(time)
currentDay = dayofmonth(time)

// Determine entry and exit conditions - Rule 1
enterLong1 = currentMonth == longEntryMonth1 and currentDay == longEntryDay1
exitLong1 = currentMonth == longExitMonth1 and currentDay == longExitDay1

// Execute strategy
if (enableRule1)
    if (enterLong1)
        strategy.entry('Long Rule 1', strategy.long)
    if (exitLong1)
        strategy.close('Long Rule 1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a timestamp out of your inputs and check if the previous bar was before that timestamp and the current bar is greater or equal to the desired date.

```
entry_ts = timestamp(year, longEntryMonth1, longEntryDay1, 0, 0, 0)
exit_ts = timestamp(year, longExitMonth1, longExitDay1, 0, 0, 0)

// Determine entry and exit conditions - Rule 1
entry_cond = (time >= entry_ts) and (time[1] < entry_ts)
exit_cond = (time >= exit_ts) and (time[1] < exit_ts)

// Execute strategy
if (enableRule1)
    if (entry_cond)
        strategy.entry('Long Rule 1', strategy.long)
    if (exit_cond)
        strategy.close('Long Rule 1')
```